# Distinguishing Data Types and Data structures

Tags: c, data-structures, types

Well, somehow even after reading in a lot of textbooks (really a lot) and on the Internet for a long while I still can’t completely comprehend what the difference between the two mentioned things is.

To simplify the question, according to let’s say Wikipedia a data type is:

> a classification identifying one of various types of data, such as real, integer or Boolean, that determines the possible values for that type; the operations that can be done on values of that type; the meaning of the data; and the way values of that type can be stored.

**with it being mostly the implementation of some Abstract data type** like the real numbers or the whole numbers.

All good, then comes the data structure:

> is a particular way of organizing data in a computer so that it can be used efficiently.[1][2] Data structures can implement one or more particular abstract data types., which are the means of specifying the contract of operations and their complexity. In comparison, **a data structure is a concrete implementation of the contract provided by an ADT**.

So a data structure is an implementation of an ADT like say a stack or queue.

But wouldn’t that make it a data type as well??

All that I can truly see is that a data type could range from really simple things without any structural organization to sophisticated structures of data what really counts is that they are an implementation of an ADT mirroring the important aspects of it and that they could be envisioned as a single entity like ( a list or tree), but data structures must contain at least some sort of logical or mathematical organization to classify as a data structure, but sadly this difference would make many entities both a data structure and a data type simultaneously.

So what is the solid difference between a simple plain (data type) and a (data structure)?

I would gladly accept an answer with specifying a specific book about this topic which goes deep enough to explain all this matters, also if someone can recommend me some good books about data structures in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, a *data type* is a language-level construct. There are a limited number of predefined types (`int`, `char`, `double`, etc.), and a practically unlimited number of *derived types* (array types, structure types, union types, function types, pointer types, atomic types (the latter are new in C11)).

Any type may be given a simple name via a `typedef` declaration. For any type other than a function type or an incomplete type, you can have *objects* of that type; each object occupies a contiguous region of memory.

The types that can exist in C are completely described in section 6.2.5 of the C standard; see, for example, the [N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

A *data structure*, on the other hand, is a construct defined by your own code. The language does not define the concept of a *linked list*, or a *binary tree*, or a *hash table*, but you can implement such a data structure, usually by building it on top of derived data types. Typically there is no such thing as an *object* that's a linked list. An instance of a linked list data structure consists of a collection of related objects, and only the logic of your code turns that collection into a coherent entity. But you'll typically have an object of some data type that your program uses to *refer* to the linked list data structure, perhaps a structure or a pointer to a structure.

You'll typically have a set of functions that operate on instances of a data structure. Whether those functions are part of the data structure is a difficult question that I won't try to answer here.

An array, for example, can be considered both a data type and a data structure; more precisely, you can think of it as a data structure implemented using the existing array type.

Comment: Ok, your answer is a lot of help, but to clarify some points. all in all you say that two things make out the difference, first is that data types are of language-level and second that only the logic of my code turns some portions of code to a coherent entity e.g. a stack or linked list. This is also further backed up by the fact that there won’t be (at least is C) a single complete entity called a stack. The problem here lies in three things. First: what do you mean by (in C, a data type is.....) does this definition differ from language to language?

Comment: (The rest) Second: the second part ( my second point ) only applies to C but not say to C++ as in C++ you can using Classes define only a single entity with all the properties and methods to comprise a single entity called stack, so would it now be considered a data type? Third: what do you mean by your last two lines (an array, for example, can be ......), can you please further explain your point here? @Keith Thompson

Comment: I answered in C terms because the question is tagged "c". Other languages might have different definitions of "type" or "data type". An object of a C++ class type is still an object; it doesn't necessarily *contain* the data that it refers to (C++'s definition of "object" is quite similar to C, and does *not* refer to "object-oriented" programming). A C array type is a *type*; it specifies a particular layout in memory. You can use it to contain a more abstract *data structure*, such as a sequence of numbers.

Comment: @KeithThompson Array as a  data type defines the operation we want , like index based search and so on . It does not specifies the particular layout in memory. Array data structure do so. Or am i wrong ?

Comment: @SurajJain: C's array types define the layout. I already said that in my previous comment.

Comment: No but it does not , data structure defines the layout. @KeithThompson

Comment: @SurajJain: Again, C's array types have a well-defined layout. [Look it up](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: Array data structure defines the memory layout array data type just provides the operation and what does they do. @KeithThompson

Comment: Oh you mean by saying array type , array data structure. ? @KeithThompson

Comment: @KeithThompson Atleast you can help someone out who is not able to understand your answer .  I read that data type describe the set , the operations done on it and constraint and result of it. So the array data type defines that index based search can happen over it , and things like that .... so index based search can happen through contiguos location in memory or through linked list.. there can be various ways... these ways are data structures.. to implement an abstract data type we need data structure.so array data structure is the data structure that allocates contiguos location in memory.

Comment: See This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376004/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-data-structure-and-an-array-data-type-in

Comment: @SurajJain: One last time. Quoting the ISO C standard, "An *array type* describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a
particular member object type, called the *element type*." That's [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.5 paragraph 20.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks , i understood this thing ...  I am just confused about one thing and what i am asking is not another question it is clarification on your answer. Does data type also tell us how to implement that particular data type , like how to store it in memory  , things like that . Maybe i am just confused between data type and abstract data type ?

Answer (score 2):

Referring >=C99:

The are two kinds of data types:

- intrinsic: `char`, `int`, `float`, `double`, `_Complex`, `_Bool`, `void` (for some of them there a variation to `long` and `unsigned` around)
- derived: arrays, structures, unions, pointers, functions

The latter are build from the former and/or the latter.

---

So to answer your question:

> So what is the solid difference between a simple plain (data type) and a (data structure)?

A "*data structure [type]*" is derived from "*simple plain data type*"(s) and/or other "*data structure [type]*"(s).

Comment: IMO, pointers are not derived from the types on the intrinsic list - especially function pointers.  I'd say pointers are also intrinsic

Comment: @chux: C11 - 6.2.50/20: "*A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the
referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference
to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T
is sometimes called ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a pointer type from a
referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. A pointer type is a complete
object type.*" :-)

Comment: So C11 - 6.2.50/20 says a pointer is "...derived from a function type or an object type...", not from an _intrinsic_.  This _intrinsic_ list well matches the spec's _object type_ which does not contain functions.

Comment: IMHO this isn't the right distinction. A linked list or a binary tree is a data structure, but it's neither an intrinsic type nor a derived type. I expand on this in my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: When answering I focused on "data types" available in the C language. Going for "data structures" in the broader (common) sense your answer is the one the OP might have been after.

Comment: @KeithThompson: But reading the question again ... hmm ... yes .. I will probably delete my answer.

Comment: What is the difference between abstract data type and data type. Does data type = abstract data type + data structure . Does data type include implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

A *data type* specifies the values and operations allowed for a single expression or object; a *data structure* is a region of storage and algorithms that organize objects in that storage.

An example of a data type is `int`; objects of this type may store whole number values in *at least* the range `[-32767, 32767]`, the usual arithmetic operations may be performed these objects (although the result of integer division is also an integer, which trips people up the first time around).  You can't use the subscript operator `[]` on an `int`, nor may you use the function call `()` operator on an `int` object.

For an example of a data structure, we can look at a simple stack.  We'll use an array as our region of storage.  We'll define an additional integer item to serve as a *stack pointer* - it will contain the index of the element most recently added to the array.  We define two algorithms - `push` and `pop` - that will add and remove items to the stack in a specific order.

```
push: if sp is less than stack size then
        add 1 to sp
        write input to array[sp]
      else
        stack overflow
      end if

 pop: if sp is greater than 0 then
        get value from array[sp]
        subtract 1 from sp
        return value
      else
        stack underflow
      end if
```

Our stack *data structure* stores a number of objects of some *data type* such that the last item added is always the first item removed, a.k.a. a last-in first-out (LIFO) queue.  If we push the values 1, 2, and 3 onto the stack, they will be popped off in the order 3, 2, and 1.

Note that it's the *algorithms* that distinguish data structures from each other, not the type of storage.  If your algorithms add an item to one end of the array and pull them from the other end, you have a first-in first-out (FIFO) queue.  If your algorithms add items to the array such that for each element `i` in the array `a[i] >= a[2*i]` and `a[i] >= a[2*i+1]` are both true, you have a heap.

Comment: What is the difference between abstract data type and data type. Does data type = abstract data type + data structure . Does data type include implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically,
A Data type defines a certain domain of values and it defines the operations allowed on those values. All the basic data types defined by the compiler are called Primitive Data Types
A Data structure is rather an User defined data type and is the systematic way to organize data so that it can be used efficiently. The operations and values of these are not specified in the language itself , but it is specified by the user.

The Book to learn more about this is "The C Programming Language - Dennis Ritchie"

Comment: "The C Programming Language" is 25 years old...  there are many more recent texts, with more up to date ideas

Answer (score 0):

A data type represents the type of data that is going to be stored in a variable. It specifies that a variable will only assign values of a specific type.
A data structure is a collection that holds various from of data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).