# array data-structure (and) array data-type how can understand the difference

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

what is the difference between array data-structure (and) array data-type. for  example from c language **int var[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}**.

- before assignment operator is int type array variable.
- after  the assignment operator is array data-structure. 
  is this correct?

Comment: No. "array data-structure" is not a standard term. It's just an array.

Comment: is really, array is not a data structure, then elements insert, delete, updates are doing, those all are basics of data structure process, so i thought it is one type of data structure

Comment: C arrays do not have insert or delete operations.

Comment: **data structure is a region of storage.** somewhere read, so i thought after '=' is arranging to store memory.  can you provide me example code for array data-type (and) array-data-structue any other context. i'm newbie please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The variable in C does not change the type after the assignment.
`int var[5]` declares variable called `var` which is and array holding 5 integers.

```
int arr[3];
int arr1[3] = {1,2,3};
```

Above arrays `arr` and `arr1` have the same type. Since array `arr` has not been initialized the values of `arr[0]` `arr[1]` `arr[2]` are undefined. The elements or array `arr1` have *integer* values as specified `arr1[0]=1` `arr1[1]=2` `arr1[2]=3`.

The confusion of terms data-structure and data-type may come from wikipedia. Read the accepted answer here: [What is the difference between an Array Data Structure and an Array Data-type in the context of a programming language like C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376004/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-data-structure-and-an-array-data-type-in)

and [Distinguishing Data Types and Data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971248/distinguishing-data-types-and-data-structures?noredirect=1&lq=1)